# Is findViewById(R.layout.my_layout) available in Android Native implementation?

Tags: android, codenameone

Is it possible to use `findViewById(R.layout.my_layout)` to find a View in my native Android implementation?

If not, how can I obtain a reference to a native view, which I create and return in a call to my Android Native Interface?

```
 public android.widget.TextView createNativeView() {
   android.widget.TextView dynamicTextView = new android.widget.TextView(AndroidNativeUtil.getContext());
   dynamicTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   dynamicTextView.setText(" Hello World ");
   dynamicTextView.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);    
   return dynamicTextView;
}
```

In my main app I am creating the Peer Component like so:

`TestNativeInterface n = TestNativeInterface)NativeLookup.create(TestNativeInterface.class);
 PeerComponent view = n.createNativeView();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that in Codename One. If you want to add the text component you can just use `add(view);` (or `add(CENTER, view);` if it's a `BorderLayout`).

Notice this will obviously only work on Android devices so to get this to work properly you will need something like:

```
Form myForm = new Form("Native", new BorderLayout());
TestNativeInterface n = TestNativeInterface)NativeLookup.create(TestNativeInterface.class);
if(n != null && n.isSupported()) {
    PeerComponent view = n.createNativeView();
    myForm.add(CENTER, view);
}
myForm.show();
```

The reason I chose to use `BorderLayout` is that it's deterministic in terms of computed size. It might take a while to calculate the preferred size for the view and layout might place it incorrectly as a result but the `CENTER` position of `BorderLayout` will stretch it across the `Form`.